# git commit -a / nano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, commit

For some reason when I try to run git commit -a I don't receive the usual controls at the bottom of nano and cannot save my edited commit message. The output is something like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
#       deleted:    app/views/comments/edit.js.erb
#       deleted:    app/views/facets/_old_menu.html.haml
#       modified:   app/views/photos/uploaded_photo.html.haml
#       deleted:    config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
#       deleted:    public/images/blue_panel_column.png
#       deleted:    public/images/embed/add_feature_button.png                                                                                       
~                                                                                           
~                                                                                           
~                                                                                           
~                                                                                           
".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 39L, 1947C
```

I've looked all over for this. I have had to manually remove .git/index.lock if this might explain it. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: `set EDITOR=vim` and you won't have any more problems with nano :P

Comment: One of these days I'll get round to learning vim, then I will understand what all the fuss is about.  :)

Comment: vim is great, you should give it a try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi just a couple of thoughts

1. Are you sure you are in nano? have
   you tried vi style commands to see
   if git has reverted back to using
   vi? [Esc :x]
2. if your commit message is small and simple, like your commit, you can use

   git commit -a -m "Your message goes here"

Hope that is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be an issue of the Mac OS X Terminal. Some but not all people using nano encountered it.

You can trick your terminal into thinking it is another one by typing:

```
TERM=VT100
export TERM
```

...or exploring the settings of your terminal (or use another one, like xterm or iTerm).

Other editors like Textmate, vim, BBedit, [...] work well. Do you have to stick with nano?

If your commit message is quite short, you can manually append it with the -m flag:

```
git commit -am "my commit message."
```

Comment: Thanks EinLama. I wish it was the problem you describe, I'd feel less stupid. :) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Haha okay ;) Nevermind as long as you can write long commit novels now :D